# Excel linest formula for weighted polynomial fit

Tags: excel

How to specify excel linest weighted polynomial fit formula, something like 
`LINEST(y*w^0.5,IF({1,0},1,x)*w^0.5,FALSE,TRUE)`, but this is for linear fit. I'm looking for similar formula for 2nd order and 3rd order polynomial regression fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a reply to the other post in [Weighted trendline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087773/weighted-trendline) an approach was already suggested for weighted polynomials. For example for a cubic fit try with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER in a 4x1 range:

```
=LINEST(y*w^0.5,(x-1E-99)^{0,1,2,3}*w^0.5,FALSE)
```

(-1e-99 ensures that 0^0=1). Similar to the linear case for R^2 try:

```
=INDEX(LINEST((y-SUMPRODUCT(y,w)/SUM(w))*w^0.5,(x-1E-99)^{0,1,2,3}*w^0.5,FALSE,TRUE),3,1)
```

*Derivation*

In standard least squares we find the vector `b` that minimises:`|y-Xb|²=(y-Xb)'(y-Xb)`

In the weighted case `b` is chosen to minimise instead: `|W(y-Xb)|²=(y-Xb)'W'W(y-Xb)`

So the weighted regression is `Wy` on `WX` where `W'W = W²` is the diagonal matrix of the weights.