# What effect has {1,0} in the IF statement logical_test, within an array function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087773/weighted-trendline/11096449#11096449), I found out how to make a weighted trendline:

```
{=LINEST(B2:B7*C2:C7^0.5,IF({1,0},1,A2:A7)*C2:C7^0.5,0)}
```

But I don't understand how this formula works.

What is Excel doing with `IF({1,0},1,x)`? What is `{1,0}`?

Comment: Added link to original answer (I had to track it down!)

Comment: Is Lori's original explanation (under "Explanation of formula" in that post) not sufficient?

Comment: I improved the title to add more details about the question and did some minor rewording for better readability. Please go through [Lori's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11096449/2246380) as its explaintion about the formula.

Comment: Lori's answer doesn't explain the use of an array constant as the logical test in an `IF` function.

Answer (score 4):

It is running the If statement twice for each row in A2:A7, once for 1 and once for 0 - that is, once as true and once as false.

So if range A2:A7 was 1 through 6 your answer would be an array that is 12 digits long and would alternate between the If statement being true, thus giving you a 1 and false, thus giving you the value from A2:A7:

{**1**,1,**1**,2,**1**,3,**1**,4,**1**,5,**1**,6}

The bold **1**s are when the If statement was using the 0 part of {1,0} and the non-bold 1 through 6 are when the if statement was using 1 part.

If you walk through it step by step it does the following: 
(remember, for excel, 1 = true and 0 = false)

```
if(1,1,A2) 'always 1
if(0,1,A2) 'always A2

if(1,1,A3) 'always 1
if(0,1,A3) 'always A3

if(1,1,A4) 'always 1
if(0,1,A4) 'always A4

If(1,1,A5) 'always 1
If(0,1,A5) 'always A5

If(1,1,A6) 'always 1
If(0,1,A6) 'always A6

{1,A2,1,A3,1,A4,1,A5,1,A6}
```