# Weighted Trendline in Excel

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula

This is an extension to the question asked in the forums a few years ago:

Excel produces scatter diagrams for sets of pair values. It also gives the option of producing a best fit trendline and formula for the trendline. It also produces bubble diagrams which take into consideration a weight provided with each value. However, the weight has no influence on the trendline or formula. Here is an example set of values, with their mappings and weights.

```
Value Map     Weight
0       1      10
1       2      10
2       5      10
3       5      20
4       6      20
5       1      1
```

I have used the formula that brettDJ offered:

```
=INDEX(LINEST(B2:B7*C2:C7^0.5,IF({1,0},1,A2:A7)*C2:C7^0.5,TRUE,TRUE),3,1)
```

However, I could not understand why we used the ^0.5 here to sqrt the weights. 
The original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087773/weighted-trendline)

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the previous question.

Comment: *I could not understand why we used the ^0.5 here to sqrt the weights* - Is this really a programming / formula question? Or rather a math question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a math question rather than a programming question.

Comment: As I understand it, ^x represents the order of the equation. For example ^3 will mean that the order of the trendline  = 3. SO how does 0.5 fit into it.